# Loader in wpf is not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I am dynamically adding the grids and each grid has some controls. When the process starts adding grids, it takes a few seconds. To gap this loading time, I have attached a loader but it is not working.

This is my code:

```
loader.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
loader.IsEnabled = true;
btnBack.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
SetDownArrow();  
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Background, 
    new Action(() => DoTimeConsumingWork())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me

```
 private void ExecuteCommand(object obj)
 {
      LabelVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
      Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
      //// Do your code here

      LabelVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reply Justin, But could you please help me out with  this  when the dispatcher thread working as background for DoTimeConsumingWork, i have a loader,this loader is showing on UI but it's rotation is not working.I think current thread struct the rotation of loader.